# Arduino programming malfunction

Tags: windows, arduino

I am learning how to use an Arduino, and of course the very thing I try to run won't work. I did have issues with drivers, which I resolved, and I have re-installed the Arduino software. I still cannot get this to work properly. My computer recognizes that the Arduino is connected.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at processing.app.EditorStatus.progress(EditorStatus.java:191)
at processing.app.Editor.handleExport(Editor.java:2415)
at processing.app.EditorToolbar.mousePressed(EditorToolbar.java:349)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6522)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3322)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4530)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Here is what I am trying to run. I had someone else in my class look at my code, and even he said it was correct. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, and I really need to get this working for class. I am terribly frustrated at this point.

```
int ledPin = 13;
int Dtime = 100;
void setup() {
pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  delay(Dtime);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  delay(Dtime);
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Comment: You issue seems to be related to the IDE setup/configuration and not to your program. Because of this (`EditorToolbar.mousePressed(EditorToolbar.java:349)
`) I have an impression that the IDE fails when it is trying to send your program to Adruino or compile - after you pressed a button on the toolbar. Maybe the compiler and tools are not installed in the location Arduino IDE is looking for them?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the latest version of java i guess. Update your JRE, download the latest version from [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/)